# How to loop/ create function for point count and ggplot for each variable in large data set?

Tags: r, function, for-loop, gps

Apologies in advance as I'm a complete novice and have been learning as I go to analyse site use using GPS data. I want to plot and rank site use (by "site_polygons") of the "site" by each distinct "name" (200+ distinct names) of 1.5 mil + rows of GPS data. I have mapped the point count per polygon and then ranked each polygon use per ha, and would like to do this for each distinct name, but have no idea how to go about this for all 200+ names. This produces a map output and rank of site_polygons per distinct name. I had a play with creating functions and looked at loops but I haven't been able to get very far with this. Grateful for any help, thank you.

edited sample data:

```
structure(list(name = c("name1", "name1", "name2", "name2", "name3", 
"name3"), 
lat = c(50.40868, 50.40881, 50.40801, 50.40592, 50.39382, 
50.43382), 
lng = c(-4.822094, -4.882094, -4.882658, -4.922658, 
-4.884558, -4.882658), 
time_stamp = structure(c(1672531320, 1672531440, 1672531560, 
1672531680, 1672531320, 1672531440), tzone = "UTC", class = 
c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), 
group = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b")), row.names = c(NA,-6L), 
class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Example data

```
name      lat       lng       time_stamp    Group
 name1 50.40868 -4.882094 01/01/2023 00:02     a
 name1 50.40880 -4.882658 01/01/2023 00:04     a
 name2 50.40801 -4.883009 01/01/2023 00:06     a
 name2 50.40592 -4.849149 01/01/2023 00:06     a
 name3 50.39382 -4.884077 01/01/2023 00:06     b
 name3 50.40868 -4.882139 01/01/2023 00:02     b
 name3 50.40880 -4.882636 01/01/2023 00:04     b
```

Site use: map point count for name1

```
library(sf)
ggplot() + geom_sf(data = site) + geom_sf(data = name1) 
inter_name1 <- st_intersects(site, name) 
site$count_name1 <- lengths(inter_name1) 
ggplot(site) + geom_sf(aes(fill = count_name1))
```

Site use of name per ha

```
site_use_name1 <- site %>% 
group_by(site_polygons) %>%         
summarise(area=sum(Area_ha),n_name1=sum(count_name1),n_name1_per_ha=n_name1/area) %>% arrange(-n_name1_per_ha)
```

Rank site use

```
ranked_name1 <- arrange(site_use_name1, desc(n_name1_per_ha)) %>% 
mutate(rank = 1:nrow(site_use_name1))
```

Comment: You may get faster and better help if you edit your question and provide a reproducible example of your data, e.g. using `dput(head(data))` and paste the output into the text. Anyway, you can try to split your data with `split(data,data$name)` into a list and run your approach with `lapply()` or a `for()` loop on each list object.

Comment: Many thanks rosapluesch. I think I've included the correct formatted sample data now.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  What you should generally aim for is a question with a minimal  reproducible example, something that others can copy-paste to their R environment to get to the same page as you in no time. You've made a good start, but to actually run your existing code and to get to the point where you already are, we would still need to reverse engineer all those missing bits. `site` seems to be an `sf` object? Can we have some samples from there or how could we simulate it? What's `site$site_polygons` ? A geometry column or some identifier? Why is it used for grouping, is it not unique?

Comment: ... What's `name` in `st_intersects(site, name) `, should it be `name1`? And is `name` the name of the dataset  with those 1.5mil points and `name1` is a subset where `name$name == "name1"`?  You have probably been working with this for the past hours or maybe days, but try putting yourself in the role of someone who just saw this question and might have few minutes to spare to look into it but then pumps into all those issues that need to be resolved first to get to the actual problem.

Comment: ... If your original datasets can't be shared and/or sampling gets too complex, perhaps use data from packages that are available for all and try to model your problem this way, i.e.  site polygons and attributes from `st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))` and GPS points sampled with `st_sample()`, adding name attributes.  You can find some general pointers on reproducible examples at https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example . Good luck!